# Change to Asp.net 4.0 got "The page cannot be found"

Tags: asp.net, iis

I've just change the existing virtual dir ASP.net version from 2.0 to 4.0 and browsed previous working web page.

But right now I'm getting an error saying "HTTP Error 404 - File or directory not found."

Any ideas?

Revert it back to ASP.net 2.0, problem went away. I've also executed "aspnet_regiis.exe -i", it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's the path to your home page? Check that your home page is included as a "Default Document" in IIS. If you're using an Application Pool, try changing the Managed Pipeline Mode to Classic, and also check that the correct .NET version is set for it (App Pool basic settings).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
You answer directed me to check Web Service Extensions. ASP.Net v4.0 prohibited there and when I allowed it, the problem went away.

Comment: A tad more info on Web Service Extensions is found here: http://www.denalimultimedia.com/info/Articles.aspx?cid=20&topic=IIS-6-ASP-NET-4-0-page-not-found-404

Answer (score 1):

At the server level, in INETMGR, select feature "ISAPI and CGI Restrictions" and set all .NET 4.0 entries to "Allow"

Answer (score 0):

1. Click "Web Service Extensions"
2. Select "ASP.NET v4.0"
3. Click "Allow" button

[image: Web Service Extensions, Allow ASP.NET v4.0]